# How load xml files, in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: xml, spring, load, ibatis, intellij-idea

IntelliJ not find xml file under sources folder.

example) src/net/saltfactory/domain/PersonSqlMap.xml

but, If I copy it and past out folder, IntelliJ find xml file

example) out/net/saltfactory/domain/PersonSqlMap.xml

I hope that don't copy and past XML files to out folder

help me

Comment: What do you mean by "find"? Are you saying IntelliJ doesn't show it or are you using the find function? Or what?

Answer (score 6):

First, make sure `src` is marked as a source folder for your module in Module Settings --> Modules -->  --> Sources.

Second, make sure the list of recognized resources includes one for XML files (`?*.xml`) in 
Settings --> Project --> Compiler --> Resource Settings.

This is how IntelliJ knows what to copy into your classpath (output folder) in addition to class files. If this doesn't help, please provide more information.

Comment: I've been looking for this as I was never able to run myBatis+xml mapper with intelliJ IDEA for years....! The second tip did the trick, and now I understand that XML files are also treated as resources.

Comment: If you use Maven, IntelliJ is smart enough to take care of this for you :-)

Comment: Man, you guys are terrible at giving direction. It's not Module Settings --> Modules --> Sources.  It's File --> Project Structure --> Modules ---> Sources.

Comment: Please note you are responding to an answer that was posted over 7 years ago. IntelliJ has changed a little since then.